# Safari position fixed inside overflow: auto

Tags: css, overflow, mobile-safari, fixed

I saw online that there were a couple of bugs related to `position: fixed` and Mobile Safari but I could'nt find any solution to my problem so far.

I have a div with `overflow: auto` and inside I have a `position: fixed` element. On desktop, Android, Chrome and Firefox, it works great but when I try to do the same on Safari on an IPhone, the behaviour is completely different and my app is not working.

The `position: fixed` element is a popup and I want it to take the whole page. Technically in safari it does take the whole page but I can only see part of my popup that is directly over the `overflow: auto` element. Everything outside the div is transparent. I say technically because the whole popup is still on top of everything but I cannot see it. I can still interact with it though.

I tried to use `position: absolute` but i my case it's not a viable option since the first element is inside another position relative ou absolute element and it's not goind to do the same thing.

The only option that a can see is to alter the overflow value when the popup is displayed and change it back when I close it.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Here is a simple code example:
https://codepen.io/belyan/full/poaKOmP